# How to allow tabs in an HTML Edit box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I know this is probably a very beginner question that I just can't seem to find the answer to but anyway.

**How do you allow a muli-line HTML edit box to allow tabs to be put into it?**(rather than tab going to the next control)

I would prefer to do this without javascript also.

Comment: +1 because your having 1337 rep seems unfair

Comment: Dang I was waiting to see how long it lasts. Now I have to get downvoted a few times lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without JavaScript.  Here's a [sample done with jQuery](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/ttabs.html) if you want to go that route.

Comment: Please add more to this answer. Making it rely upon a link is bad-practice.

Comment: Well he didn't want to use JavaScript so my answer is really "You can't do this." I just provided additional resources.  ;)

Comment: Well, I sometimes don't consider jQuery to be javascript because it's so simple :) and this would be trivial javascript to add even to a asp.net webapp, so jQuery it is!

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32317):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function replaceSelection (input, replaceString) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
        var selectionStart = input.selectionStart;
        var selectionEnd = input.selectionEnd;
        input.value = input.value.substring(0, selectionStart)+ replaceString + input.value.substring(selectionEnd);

        if (selectionStart != selectionEnd){ 
            setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionStart +   replaceString.length);
        }else{
            setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart + replaceString.length, selectionStart + replaceString.length);
        }

    }else if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range.parentElement() == input) {
            var isCollapsed = range.text == '';
            range.text = replaceString;

             if (!isCollapsed)  {
                range.moveStart('character', -replaceString.length);
                range.select();
            }
        }
    }
}


// We are going to catch the TAB key so that we can use it, Hooray!
function catchTab(item,e){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match("Gecko")){
        c=e.which;
    }else{
        c=e.keyCode;
    }
    if(c==9){
        replaceSelection(item,String.fromCharCode(9));
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('"+item.id+"').focus();",0);    
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea name="data" id="data" rows="20" columns="35" wrap="off" onkeydown="return catchTab(this,event)" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild hunch but I think you'd want to have multiple HTML edit boxes on the page, then use javascript (like jQuery) to place them into separate tabs.

The tabs will require some sort of javascript to create the interaction.

(ugh. Disregard. I was thinking visual user interface tabs. Not the tab character.)

Comment: I think he meant Tab as a series of spaces (Tab key on keyboard), and I'm not sure you mean that. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="textbox" />

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--


    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    if (textbox.addEventListener)
        textbox.addEventListener("keydown", this.textbox_keyHandler, false);
    else if (textbox.attachEvent)
        textbox.attachEvent("onkeydown", this.textbox_keyHandler);
    function textbox_keyHandler(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 9)
        {
            var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
            textbox.value += "\t";
            if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: This will not work as expected if the cursor isn't at the end of the textbox.